# How to use an UPDATE Query with an INNER JOIN to update fields within a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, inner-join, not-exists

I keep getting a run time error on the following SQL statement:

```
UPDATE tbl_1 
INNER JOIN tbl_2 ON tbl_1.PersNo = tbl_2.PersNo 
SET tbl_1.Marked = 'N/A' 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tbl_2 WHERE tbl_1.PersNo = tbl_2.PersNo)
```

I think I may have some syntax backward, I'm looking to update the Table 1 Marked field with "N/A" (string value) when the PersNo does not exist in Table 2.

This all stems from a function with several SQL statments that allow me to Update the Table 1 Marked field with either "Yes", "No", or "N/A". So if there is a simpler way to do this, I'm open to suggestions.

In short, if the PersNo exists in Table 2 and the Type (from Table 2) is "Summary" then update Table 1 Marked field with "Yes", but is the Type (from Table 2) is "Full" then update Table 1 Marked field with "No", and is the PersNo does not exist in Table 2, update Table 1 Marked field with "N/A".

Comment: Show the complete error message - ALL of it. Yes. the syntax is wrong but no one should need to guess.

Comment: From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql): [`SET` comes before `FROM`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQGXH.jpg).

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is indeed incorrect for SQL Server - *if* I understand your last paragraph you just need a conditional *case expression*. If the following (of course untested) is not correct hopefully it's enough to put you on the right track:

```
update t1 set t1.Marked =
    case t2.type
      when 'Summary' then 'Yes'
      when 'Full' then 'No'
      else 'N/A'
    end
from tbl_1 t1
left join tbl_2 t2 on t1.PersNo = t2.PersNo;
```

Answer (score 3):

Part of the issue is SQL Server likes you to use table aliases and a `FROM` clause when using a `JOIN` with an `UPDATE`, and the `SET` comes before the tables:

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.Marked = 'N/A' 
FROM tbl_1 t1
INNER JOIN tbl_2 t2 ON t1.PersNo = t2.PersNo 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tbl_2 WHERE t1.PersNo = tbl_2.PersNo)
```

This isn't exactly ansi standard for UPDATES with JOINs, but I like it because it makes it easy to write a SELECT query first and then quickly translate it into an UPDATE.

But now we've got this far the logic seems wrong. If the `NOT EXISTS()` succeeds, the `JOIN` condition won't match any rows, so nothing will change. For this part, you need  to think more on what you're trying to do. Based on the written description, I think you want this:

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.Marked = CASE WHEN t2.Type='Summary' THEN 'Yes'
                        WHEN t2.Type='Full' THEN 'No'
                        ELSE 'N/A' END 
FROM tbl_1 t1
LEFT JOIN tbl_2 t2 ON t1.PersNo = t2.PersNo 
    AND t2.Type IN ('Summary', 'Full')
```

---

> This all stems from a [procecdure] with several SQL statments that allow me to Update the Table 1 Marked field with either "Yes", "No", or "N/A". So if there is a simpler way to do this, I'm open to suggestions.

I'd bet good money it's possible to consolidate all or most of those steps into a single query that will perform the same job in a small fraction of the time, but to help with that we'd have to see the whole procedure.